# Iterating TouchCollection creates garbage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, garbage-collection, monogame

I am developing a MonoGame WP8 app. In each update loop I fetch the latest input like so

```
public TouchCollection CurrentTouchState { get; protected set; }
```

I populate this property as follows

```
CurrentTouchState = TouchPanel.GetState();
```

And then I iterate though it

```
foreach (TouchLocation touchLocation in CurrentTouchState) { ... }
```

According to the memory profiler, this iteration is creating a lot of garbage each frame

[image]

3510 instances were created over the course of ~2 secs. Garbage collection is currently an issue which is causing a lot of stuttering in my app. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

A partial fix was committed yesterday. Try building a fresh version from https://github.com/mono/MonoGame

Comment: I downloaded the latest build and it's dependinces then built the project in ARM Release mode. The bin folder contained a lot of .dll, among them is MonoGame.Framework.dll. I took only that and placed it in my project instead of the NuGet reference, but now I get an exception on launch 'Could not load file or assembly 'SharpDX, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. How to fix this?

Comment: You also need to copy SharpDX from `ThirdParty/Dependencies`

Comment: Ok so now it runs, but the first time I ran the app, as soon as I touched the screen I got an exception in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch whose message is 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.', but strangely it doesn't happen on every subsequent run, only every few runs. Screenshot -> http://imgur.com/SNvEhAY

Comment: There still seems to be memory issues after profiling, only difference now is that they dont make sense http://imgur.com/fOnWrES In my InputManager.Update all I basically do is 'CurrentTouchState = TouchPanel.GetState();' and 'while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable) Gestures.Add(TouchPanel.ReadGesture());'

Comment: Any thoughts on what is going on in my last comment regarding the weird memory profile report?

Comment: `TouchCollection` has not been optimized for zero allocations yet. This is a known issue - seeing a bug report with concrete numbers will bump this in priority.